# wrong value when converting String date to date Object

Tags: java

When I convert String date like "18/09/13,02:01:51"
Using this method:

```
public static Date stringToDateFormat(String dateString) {
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy,hh:mm:ss").parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

When I save this convert this date object to SQL Date and store it in PostgreSQL Database, I lose the time
2013-09-18 00:00:00

Here the DB insertion code"

```
String query = "INSERT INTO My_Table(my_date) VALUES (?)";

Date date = stringToDateFormat("18/09/13,02:01:51");

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Is it coding problem or DB configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: You are specifying down to the second, not the millisecond.

Comment: OK, this is not the issue, I didnt explain the whole problem, I will edit the question

Comment: If you print the value of the `Date` object between string conversion and saving in the DB, what does it contain?

Comment: lets say I wanna save this Date: 18/09/13,02:01:51
it appears in the DB as 18/09/13,00:00:00

Answer (score 2):

Your date string does not specify ms and is being rounded.

```
18/09/13,02:01:51 == 1379458917000

18/09/13,02:01:51.590 == 1379458917590
```

**Update**:

A format string which captures MS would be: `dd/MM/yy,hh:mm:ss.SSS`

Comment: I would be a better answer if it included the format that would correct the issue ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Added. Though it looks like the OP has a new problem which may or may not be solved by a better format string.

Comment: At least it gives them some place to start ;)

Comment: This is the exact date that I found saved in the DB 2013-09-18 00:00:00, I dont understand why it the time is 00:00:00 hours minutes and seconds must be different value

Comment: For an answer to that, you'll have to pose the code where you insert the date.